# How to properly set the backgroundColor for a screen imported in React-native?

Tags: react-native, import, fullscreen, background-color

i still learning react-native and want to set the backgroundColor to an entire screen which is imported in app.js.

Even if i set the flex in 1, the height covering the screen but the width is always center but not covering the entire screen.

Here what i'm doing:

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import Splash from "./Screen/Splash";
import TestScreen from "./Screen/TestScreen";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <Splash /> */}
      <TestScreen />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

TestScreen.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 168, 150)",
  },
});

export default Test;
```

So,how i can set properly the backgroundColor to ScreenTest to cover the entire screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within app.js maybe add the full-width property:

```
<TestScreen style = {styles.redbox} >


container: {
         flex: 1
     },
redbox: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
   },
```

Comment: thanks, it works with your proposition but normally accordind to the documentation:  https://reactnative.dev/docs/height-and-width#flex-dimensions when you set the flex to 1 the background should be fill all the space available...